# Perl using varying elements in an array for a user option menu

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, menu

I have an array called `@option`

Each time the script is run the `@option` could contain both different elements and a different number of elements

The first time the script is run it might contain

> dog, cat, antelope, elephant, pig

The second time the script is run it might contain

> horse, elephant, goat

**What I need:**
Using the elements from the array, prompt the user to select the element, either by typing in the array element string 
or entering a value each element in the array is linked with,
or any other better method that you can think of.

For example:

```
Please select which one you want to delete by entering its associated number:
dog[1] 
cat[2] 
antelope[3]
elephant[4]
pig[5]
```

(after the user selects one the rest of my code will do stuff and then delete it).

I know I could do this using *if STDIN matches dog do this, if it matches elephant do that and so on*.

**What I am actually looking for is** suggestions for different methods people consider as the *best/most efficient/most acceptable/professional/preferred/clever* way of doing this.

Comment: Be careful with questions like this — they are in danger of being closed and classified as 'Not Constructive': _As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion._

Comment: Have you looked at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) for menu-driven systems?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - Yes I have looked at CPAN, where there's a number of solutions, but ideally I was looking for the best method, without having to use a module, also thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with, which allows you to have a string for querying for the input and does checking make sure the response is valid.  If not, it will query the user again.  The subroutine returns the index of the array item selected.

```
sub displayMenu($@)
{
  # First item is the query string, so shift it 
  # from the inputs and save it 
  my $queryString = shift @_;
  # Loop control variable;
  my $lcv;
  # User selection of choices
  my $selection;
  # Flag to indicate you have the correct input
  my $notComplete = 1;

  # Clear some space on the screen
  print "\n" x 10;
  # Loop until you have an answer
  while ( $notComplete ) 
  {

    print "-" x 40 . "\n";
    for( $lcv = 1; $lcv <= scalar(@_) ; $lcv++ ) 
    {
      printf " %4d)  %s\n",$lcv,$_[$lcv-1];
    }
    print "\n";
    # Query for a response
    print "$queryString\n";
    # Get response
    $selection = <STDIN>;
    # Remove the carriage return
    chomp($selection);

    # Check to make sure it is string of digits
    # and it is within the range of the numbers
    # If it is, clear the not complete flag
    if (( $selection =~ m/^\d*/ ) && 
    ( 0 < $selection ) && ( scalar(@_) >= $selection)) 
    {
      $notComplete = 0;
    }
    # Else there is a error so try again
    else
    {
      print "\n" x 10;
      print "\nIncorrect Input.  Try again\n";
    }
  }

  # Return the index of the selected array item
  return ($selection - 1);
}
```

An example of how to call it is as follows:

```
$returnValue = displayMenu("Enter number of the item you want to select",("Test1","Test2","Test3"));
```

Where the first item in the call is the string to print for the input of the selection, followed by the array of items from which to select.  It then returns in index from the selection.

*Answers to your questions from the comments below.  My answer was to long to be in a comment.*

If you break down the `printf " %4d) %s\n",$lcv,$_[$lcv-1]` into parts, the printf is for function for formatting output.  The first argument to print if is a string indicating the format of line followed by the the items which supply the values to be formatted.  In this case the %4d is to print out a integer and that it should occupy 4 spaces on the line, and the %s is to print out a string.The next items are the arguments for the format specifiers, in this case $lcv is the number of the choice (%4d) and `$_[$lcv-1]` is the choice (the $lcv-1 is because the array in zero based index and $_ is to access the arguments where where passed to the routine. NOTE: I shifted the first argument of the items passed in to get the title) for the %s.  If you look at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html it gives a description of the various format specifier (sprintf is to print to a string, but the format specifiers are the same for printf).

The `( 0 < $selection ) && ( scalar(@_) >= $selection))` is to make sure the the input is within the given range of choices.  The selection should be greater then zero and less then or equal to the number of items which where choices, which is what the `scalar(@_)` returns (`@_` refers to the arguments passed in to the routine and the scalar function return the number of items in the array).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is exactly what i required. Would you be able to explain to me in a bit more detail what the following lines do please, they are 'printf " %4d)  %s\n",$lcv,$_[$lcv-1];' and '( 0 < $selection ) && ( scalar(@_) >= $selection))', as i am a little unsure, thanks for your help

Comment: My answer would not fit in the comment, so I added it to the answer above.  Glad to be of assistance and that it was useful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much that has helped me a lot, you explained it perfectly, thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to do some validation.

```
for my $id (1 .. scalar @options) {
  my $element = $options[$id - 1];
  say "$id: $element";
}
my $input = <STDIN>;
my $selection = $options[$input - 1];
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the kind of thing I was looking for, Would you consider this the preferred method of doing something like this then, or just one of the many options?

Comment: When you mentioned 'You'd need to do some validation' , what was you referring to? Thanks.

Comment: It's about as basic as you can get -- iterate over the number of elements in the array, print out the id and the number of elements, then get the selection by the index. (shifted one, as indices count from 0 and ids usually count from 1)

Comment: That they're not inputting 'asdf' for example, and handling a reprompt if so.

Comment: Thanks, just answered my question, I see what you mean now.

Comment: When you say it's 'as basic as you can get' do you mean that as a good thing, and that it would be the best method to use in this case? Or would there be a preferred, more complicated way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like

```
sub get_user_selection {
  my(@choices) = @_;
  my $index = 1;
  for my $choice (@choices) {
    print "$index.) $choices[$index - 1]\n";
    $index++;
  }
  print "Enter your choice: ";
  return $choices[<STDIN> - 1];
}
```

This subroutine will display a menu, and return the value the user has selected by entering the number.

Comment: Thanks, this was also the kind of thing I was looking for, will give them both a try.